# changing font size of \caption*

Tags: captions, citing, subcaption, cite-package

I want to change the font size of the \caption* command, which is not listed in the list of figures.

I have the following code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   This is a figure
\caption{Time Line for an Event Study}
\caption*{Source: own diagram based on \cite{campbell1997}}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I would like to have the Source text in a smaller font, as well as left aligned with the Figure 1 caption.

Also: i need to make sure that the `\cite{}` command works in the caption

Comment: The above code compiles for you? I don't see \begin- or \end{document} anywhere?

Comment: Consider using an alternative like `\source` rather than `\caption*`. And, why does `Source: ...` have to left-align with `Figure X: ...`? you're probably using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to format the above captions... could you include that in your post?